# C sprintf causing a segmentation fault

Tags: c, process, segmentation-fault, parent, printf

I am trying to pass in arguments to the a parent file that is supposed to create a child process for each pair of arguments. The child processes will add up each pair and return their sum to the parent process. If there is an odd number of arguments passed in, I add a 0 to the end of the argv array to make it even. This keeps happening until all the arguments have been added up, and their sum is printed at the end.

Everything is working fine except when I pass in an even amount of arguments. A child process will successfully add the first two arguments and return them, but then when the parent does a `sprintf`, (line 58) there is always a `segmentation fault`.

Here is the code for both the parent and child processes (I am using pastebin so it doesn't look very cluttered here. They will expire in one day, so I could re-post them if needed):

- http://pastebin.com/zCB700Et
- http://pastebin.com/VxXKYrdn

The second file has to be called `worker` when it is compiled in order to be run by the first file. I am using `gcc` on `Ubuntu 9.10`

Here are a few examples on how to run the program:

```
gcc -o parent parent.c
gcc -o worker worker.c
./parent 1 2 3 4
```

(The above example will end with a `segmentation fault` like I explained above). The answer should be `10` because `(1 + 2) + (3 + 4) = 10`.

This one below will work fine though with an odd number of arguments being passed in:

```
./parent 1 2 3
```

The answer to this one should be `6`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You have a bug. The bug is not in `sprintf`.

Comment: It's more than a bug; it's a misunderstanding of how things work. The program seems to be trying to do exactly what he wants it to do - and that's the problem :-)

Comment: @Alok: I just made the links clickable (which the OP couldn't do since he only had 1 rep), so hopefully that makes your life easier.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I first started making this program, out of curiosity I tried adding to the artray, and it seemed to work. That is why I tried going further with that, but I realize now that I shouldn't be modifying argv and argc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C standard allows one to modify the strings pointed-to by `argv`:

> The parameters `argc` and `argv` and the strings pointed to by the `argv` array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination.

But it doesn't guarantee you to write past the available number of arguments in `argv`, which is what you are doing when you store the sum at the end of `argv`.

You seem to be using `argv[i]` for `char *` variables.  Why not just declare separate variables for the purpose of storing the sum?  You also don't need to store `"0"` in `argv[argc-1]` if the number of numbers to sum is odd—you can easily determine that in your loop, and pass `"0"` to the last worker.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 3):

Overwriting the argument list is, at best, a serious perversion, and at worst a guaranteed fault. That's what you're doing in your sprintf call - the first argument you pass it is one of the strings passed to main().  Why are you doing that?

[edit] I see you've even got a comment to that effect.  Well, I don't know what you think is supposed to happen when you do that; if you explain your thinking then somebody may be able to explain where you've gotten confused. You can't add new stuff to the "argv" array. It makes no sense. That's something allocated by the system when launching your process, and you should basically treat it as being read-only (unless you really know what you're doing).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So I should copy all of the new sums to a separate integer array then? I thought I could just keep my for loop going by adding all the new sums at the end and incrementing argc

Comment: Maybe it's a homegrown `setproctitle`! :-P

Comment: @Dave what is it that you expect will happen when you add strings to the argument list?  In other words, what's the goal?  What made you think that that was a good idea? (Not making fun of you; I'm trying to get to the bottom of what it is you're trying to accomplish.)

Comment: I wanted to keep the loop going by just adding all of the new sums to the argv array. In other words, I thought it would be simple because I wouldn't have to convert the integers returned back from the child process to strings and then add them to a new char array.

Answer (score 0):

```
        argc++;
        sprintf(argv[argc-1],"%d",tmp);
```

you are getting out of the array boundaries here. btw, what is use to write to argv ?

Comment: Hello, the code you put write there is what I am using to add values to the argv array.

Comment: The beauty of C is that it's just memory.  The argv array isn't an array like in PHP or javascript, where you can dynamically add items and it understands. All the [] operator does is access a piece of memory at a given offset.  Since the size of the array is fixed, you're trying to access a piece of memory outside its control.  This could cause any number of odd behaviors (from a segfault to just weird heisenbugs).  In short, don't do it!! :)